# SQL multiple joins using primary keys only one has type = eq_ref on EXPLAIN

Tags: mysql, join, primary-key

So I have a database with about 40,000 records and each entry has two id fields that relate to different tables. An example query would be:

`SELECT a.*, c.full_name, em.full_name FROM records AS r JOIN customers c ON a.customer_id = c.customer_id JOIN employees em ON a.employee_id = em.employee_id`

This query takes about 5 seconds. 
When I try to `EXPLAIN` the query, I see that the customers table has a `type` of `eq_ref` while the employees table has a `type` of `ALL` even though both join conditions are referencing the primary key of the joined table. This is clearly slowing the query down tremendously because `EXPLAIN` shows that the customers table is only using 1 row, while the employees table is using 474 rows. Why is the employees table not joining as a `type` of `eq_ref` and using only 1 row?

[image: Image of results from MySQL optimizer]

Comment: Not an answer, but your query could be done with any join order for the 3 tables and be logically equivalent.  So, the MySQL optimizer is free to choose the order which it thinks would give the best performance.  Of course, the left most table in the join is just going to be a full table scan.

Comment: So the leftmost should scan all, but the rightmost should only scan 1, yet it is also scanning all for some reason. `employee_id` is the primary key, yet the `type` is displaying as `ALL`

Comment: I think you should post the full query plan, if it can fit nicely in your question.  I'm not sure there is anything wrong or unexpected here.

Comment: Sorry. Pls excuse my ignorance. What do you mean by query plan?

Comment: You don't seem ignorant at all actually.  I just mean post the full output you got from running `EXPLAIN`.  The optimizer isn't stupid, and if it's doing it this way, there is probably a reason for it.

Comment: Delete that comment and put that information, formatted, into your question.

Comment: Will do. Sry about that. wasn't sure how that would format

Comment: How do I add a table to my question?

Comment: Just add four spaces to each line.  This will make the font monospaced, and then you can easily format as a table.

Comment: I couldn't get the table to work, so i put it into excel and added screenshot to question

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual complete query? Your explain plan indicates you have both an `order by` and a `where`-condition; also `a` is never declared (is it `records as a` instead of `records as r`?). This would (or rather could) be a completely different query than what you are asking for, so please share the actual query (or the actual explain plan), not just a part of it. And also the table definitions (the output of `show create table yourtablename`, you can remove irrelevant columns if you like, but primary key and indexes and all columns you use in your query should be included).

Comment: Sry. When I was editing the query to keep out sensitive info I changed a to r. In the real query they are the same (the query works, just very slowly)